# AVAssetExportSession Crop Video Transformation problem

Tags: ios, swift, video

I am trying to crop the video with `AVMutableComposition`. The exported video seem rotated to an unknown angle. It does not even choose the correct frame from the video. I have debugged the frame, and the provided crop frame is correct. Even if the video's `preferredTransformation` is `Identity`, then too it does not crop the correct video.

My code is like below:

```
public func exportVideo(asset: AVAsset, destinationDirectory: URL? = nil, editingOptions: MediaEditingOptions? = nil,
                            completion: @escaping VideoExportCompletion) -> ExportOperation? {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()

        guard let videoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid),
              let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
            completion(.failure(Error.couldNotAddMutableTracks))
            return nil
        }

        let timeRange = editingOptions?.videoEditingOptions.timeRange ?? CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)
        if let videoAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first {
            do {
                try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: videoAssetTrack, at: .zero)
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            completion(.failure(Error.couldNotFindVideoTrack))
            return nil
        }

        if let audioAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first {
            do {
                try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audioAssetTrack, at: .zero)
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return nil
            }
        }

        let preset = editingOptions?.videoEditingOptions.preset ?? VideoEditingOptions.defaultPreset
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: preset) else {
            completion(.failure(Error.couldNotInitiateExportSession))
            return nil
        }

        guard var exportURL = destinationDirectory ?? cacheDirectoryURL() else {
            completion(.failure(Error.couldNotDetermineOutputDirectory))
            return nil
        }

        /// Prepare Instructions
        let compositionInstructions = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        compositionInstructions.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)

        let layerInstructions = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
        let cropFrame = editingOptions?.scrollBounds ?? CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoTrack.naturalSize.width, height: videoTrack.naturalSize.height)

        let transform = getTransform(for: videoTrack, cropFrame: cropFrame)
        layerInstructions.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)
        layerInstructions.setOpacity(1.0, at: CMTime.zero)
        compositionInstructions.layerInstructions = [layerInstructions]

        /// Add video composition.
        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComposition.renderSize = cropFrame.size
        videoComposition.instructions = [compositionInstructions]
        videoComposition.frameDuration = videoTrack.minFrameDuration

        exportURL.appendPathComponent(UUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
        exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
        exportSession.outputURL = exportURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
            if exportSession.status == .failed {
                completion(.failure(exportSession.error ?? Error.unknown))
            } else if exportSession.status == .completed {
                completion(.success(exportURL))
            } else {
                completion(.failure(Error.unknown))
            }
        }

        return exportSession
    }

    func getTransform(for videoTrack: AVAssetTrack, cropFrame: CGRect) -> CGAffineTransform {
        let renderSize = cropFrame.size
        let renderScale = renderSize.width / cropFrame.width
        let offset = CGPoint(x: -cropFrame.origin.x, y: -cropFrame.origin.y)
        let rotation = atan2(videoTrack.preferredTransform.b, videoTrack.preferredTransform.a)

        var rotationOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        if videoTrack.preferredTransform.b == -1.0 {
            rotationOffset.y = videoTrack.naturalSize.width
        } else if videoTrack.preferredTransform.c == -1.0 {
            rotationOffset.x = videoTrack.naturalSize.height
        } else if videoTrack.preferredTransform.a == -1.0 {
            rotationOffset.x = videoTrack.naturalSize.width
            rotationOffset.y = videoTrack.naturalSize.height
        }

        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: renderScale, y: renderScale)
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: offset.x + rotationOffset.x, y: offset.y + rotationOffset.y)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: rotation)

        print("track size \(videoTrack.naturalSize)")
        print("preferred Transform = \(videoTrack.preferredTransform)")
        print("rotation angle \(rotation)")
        print("rotation offset \(rotationOffset)")
        print("actual Transform = \(transform)")
        return transform
    }
```

I don't find anything obvious here. Am I missing anything here?